# Use DataTable and Ajax in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am learning to use DataTable with Ajax.

I'm getting my data via next function, which is querying the data from a database:

```
function loadTable() {
            $.getJSON('/admin/users3/qryUsers')
                .done(function (data) {
                    console.log('data', data);
                    // Clear tbody tag
                    $('tbody').empty();
                    // Loop over each item in the array
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        let tr = `<tr>
                               <td>${value.id}</td>
                               <td>${value.name}</td>
                               <td>${value.email}</td>
                               <td>${value.active}</td>
                               <td>${value.admin}</td>
                               <td data-id="${value.id}"
                                   data-name="${value.name}"
                                   data-email="${value.email}"
                                   data-active="${value.active}"
                                   data-admin="${value.admin}">
                                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                        <a href="#!" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit ${value.name}">
                                            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#!" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-delete" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete ${value.name}">
                                            <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                               </td>
                           </tr>`;
                        $('tbody').append(tr);
                    });
                })
                .fail(function (e) {
                    console.log('error', e);
                })
        }
```

With this function:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#table_id').DataTable();
            loadTable();
        });
```

I can load the data into a table, but when I click on a header to sort all data dissapears visually, same with the search field. I know I probably have to redraw the table or something, but
as said I'm new to this and don't really seem to be able to get started yet, I'm hoping anyone could help me!

EDIT:
I now tried this:

```
$.getJSON('/admin/users3/qryUsers')
                .done(function (data) {
                    console.log('data', data);
                    $('#table_id').DataTable({
                        "ajax": data,
                        "columns": [
                            {"data": "id"},
                            {"data": "name"},
                            {"data": "email"},
                            {"data": "active"},
                            {"data": "admin"}
                        ]
                    });
                })
                .fail(function (e) {
                    console.log('error', e);
                });
```

and got error: DataTables warning: table id=table_id - Invalid JSON response.
I've already looked into this and checked my json response via jsonlint but it seems to be valid

QryUsers method:

```
public function qryUsers()
    {
        $users = User::orderBy('name')
            ->get();
        return $users;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are manipulating the table directly by adding `tr` elements **after** initializing the DataTable. This is not recommended way to work with DataTables.

Quick way to fix your code is to manipulate the table **before** initializing the table. For example, remove `$('#table_id').DataTable()` call and place it in `done()` function.

```
$.getJSON('/admin/users3/qryUsers')
    .done(function (data) {
        // Populate table

        // Initialize DataTable plug-in
        $('#table_id').DataTable();
     });
```

However best way would be to let DataTables handle Ajax call, see [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) for code and demonstration.